# How can I use classes/methods from project that refer project, that I referring in my current solution?

Tags: c#, architecture, project, projects-and-solutions

I have three projects: Project1, Project2, Project3. In Project 2 set reference to Project1. In Project3 set reference to Project2. How can I access/use classes and methods that located in Project1 from Project3??

Comment: You need to reference Project1 in Project3.

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wkze6zky.aspx

Comment: References aren't transitive. However, if `Project2` *exposes* types from `Project1`, the build system will point out when you *have* to add the reference to `Project1`.

Comment: All projects are Windows form project ?

Comment: @Saliou673 No. They just Class Library.

Comment: Is referencing same project from Project2 and Project3 will be architecturally right?

Comment: I am actually build MVVM application, where Project2 contains ModelView and Project3 contains View. By your suggestion I should from both reference Project1(which is third party library).